# Can I remove an image from the Gallery without deleting it from the Media Library?

Tags: plugins, gallery, media-library

From what I've looked, I don't think is built-it.
Is there a plugin that implements this feature or a workaround for this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes, check the plugin [Post2Media](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/post2media/). The plugin [adds checkboxes](http://s.wordpress.org/extend/plugins/post2media/screenshot-2.png?r=555527) to the images of a gallery, and you can uncheck images you don’t want to see in the gallery.